# HDD seq. read performance

Tags: performance, memory, storage, datacenter

I read the specs for one of the latest Hitachi HDD, https://www.hgst.com/sites/default/files/resources/USC10K1800_ds.pdf . It indicates a speed of

SAS 12 Gb/s

which is 1.5 GB/s. Is it the sequential read speed for this HDD? seems to be a lot. If not, what is the sequential read speed for this kind of HDD?

What is also IOPS 100%R / 100%W ?

Answer (score 1):

> SAS 12 Gb/s
>
> which is 1.5 GB/s. Is it the sequential read speed for this HDD? seems
>   to be a lot.

12 Gb/s is the SAS interconnect speed, which has little to no bearing on how fast the disk can actually read data off of its platters.

> If not, what is the sequential read speed for this kind of HDD?

This depends your use case - what filesystem you're using, how it's configured, what block size the disk is formatted with, etc.

Like with [all capacity planning topics](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning), you'll need to profile the drive with your data, and your expected use pattern to get useful data.

> What is also IOPS 100%R / 100%W ?

R = Read, W = Write.

You can't have both 100% read & 100% write. Those two percentages need to add up to 100%. When performing drive benchmarks, you'll typically see tests at 50R/50W, 80R/20W, etc.

Comment: thanks. in most specs, there is an indicative performance for sequential read/write. is it the sustained transfer rate figure in same Hitachi data sheet? what about IOPS (which corresponds to a random access to 4kb data files)?

Comment: Yes, sequential read/write is equivalent to sustained transfer rate.  I'm not sure what you mean by "what about IOPS" -- that *is* random access.  The available IOPS of a drive is usually about the reciprocal of seek time.